# Getting Hashicorp Provider Error while creating aks cluster using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, hashicorp

I am getting error while creating AKS Cluster Using Terraform

## Error:

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages
Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/file: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/file

All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when using a module. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/file, run the following command:
    terraform providers
```

Above is the error i am facing. I have written Terraform code as shown below.

```
provider.tf:
============

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.39.0"
    }
  }
}


terraform.tfvars:
=================

resource_group_name = "a0474899701"
location            = "CentralUS"
cluster_name        = "aks01"
kubernetes_version  = "1.24.4"
system_node_count   = 2
user_node_count     = 1
spot_node_count     = 2
acr_name            = "devops_acr_tf"
aks_network_plugin  = "kubenet"
client_id           = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


main.tf:
========
# Create an Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks-rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
}

# Create an ACR instance
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = var.acr_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks-rg.name
  location            = var.location
  sku                 = "Standard"
  admin_enabled       = false
}

# Create a role assignment to allow AKS to access ACR
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "role_acrpull" {
  scope                            = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  role_definition_name             = "AcrPull"
  # principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity.0.object_id
  principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kubelet_identity.0.client_id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}

# Create a Kubernetes secret to hold the ACR credentials
# It holds the ACR credentials in a Docker config JSON format
resource "kubernetes_secret" "acr_credentials" {
  metadata {
    name = "acr-credentials"
  }

  data = {
    ".dockerconfigjson" = azurerm_container_registry.acr.docker_config_json
  }
}    

# Private Key Creation
resource "tls_private_key" "aks_ssh_key" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
}

resource "tls_public_key" "aks_ssh_key" {
  private_key_pem = tls_private_key.aks_ssh_key.private_key_pem
}

resource "file" "private_key" {
  content  = tls_private_key.aks_ssh_key.private_key_pem
  filename = "aks_private_key.pem"
}

# virtual network (aks_vnet) is created in the same resource group
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks_vnet" {
  name                = "${var.resource_group_name}-vnet01"
  # address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  address_space       = ["10.172.144.0/26"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
}

# subnet (aks_subnet) is created within the virtual network
resource "azurerm_subnet" "aks_subnet" {
  name                 = "${var.resource_group_name}-vnet01-subnet01"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks_vnet.name
  # address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"
  address_prefix       = "10.172.144.0/27"
}


resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "azure-sg" {
  name                = "${var.resource_group_name}-nsg01"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks_rg.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "allow-ssh"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = var.cluster_name
  kubernetes_version  = var.kubernetes_version
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.aks-rg.name
  security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.azure-sg.name
  dns_prefix          = var.cluster_name
  
  default_node_pool {
    name                = "system"
    node_count          = var.system_node_count
    vm_size             = "Standard_E4as_v4"
    os_disk_size_gb     = 20
    os_disk_type        = "Ephemeral"
    vnet_subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.id
    os_type             = "Linux"
    node_image_version = "AKSUbuntu-1804gen2containerd-2023.01.10"
    enable_node_public_ip = false
    enable_auto_scaling = false
  }
  additional_node_pools {
    name                = "user"
    node_count          = var.user_node_count
    vm_size             = "Standard_E8as_v4"
    os_disk_size_gb     = 20
    os_disk_type        = "Ephemeral"
    vnet_subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.id
    type                = "User"
      # os_type             = "RedHat"
    os_type             = "Linux"
    node_image_version = "AKSUbuntu-1804gen2containerd-2023.01.10"
    enable_node_public_ip = false
    enable_auto_scaling = false
  }
  additional_node_pools {
    name                = "spot"
    node_count          = var.spot_node_count
    vm_size             = "Standard_D2s_v3"
    os_disk_size_gb     = 20
    os_disk_type        = "Ephemeral"
    vnet_subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.id
    type                = "User"
      # os_type             = "RedHat"
    os_type             = "Linux"
    node_image_version = "AKSUbuntu-1804gen2containerd-2023.01.10"
    max_price           = 0.5
    enable_node_public_ip = false
    enable_auto_scaling = false
    eviction_policy      = "Spot"
    taints               = ["kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority=spot:NoSchedule"]
    labels = {
      "kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority" = "spot"
    }
  }

  kubernetes_cluster_config {
    max_pods_per_node = "110"
  }
  
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  
  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "azureuser"

    ssh_key {
      key_data = tls_public_key.aks_ssh_key.public_key_openssh
    }
  }
  
  network_profile {
    pod_cidr = "172.32.0.0/19"
    service_cidr = "172.32.0.0/19"
    load_balancer_sku = "Standard"
    network_plugin    = var.aks_network_plugin 
    dns_service_ip = "172.32.0.10"
    docker_bridge_cidr = "172.34.0.1/16"
  }
  
  service_principal {
    client_id     = var.client_id
    client_secret = var.client_secret
  }
  
  tags = {
    Environment = "Development"
  }
}

# ACR can be attached to the AKS cluster using the "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_container_registry_config" resource type
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_container_registry_config" "acr_config" {
  cluster_name        = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.name
  registry_id         = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  namespace           = "aks"
  default_action      = "Allow"
}
```

Above is my Code I am facing above error. even i have changed my provider.tf still facing same issue. Can anyone please tell me How to solve this error

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you are using? Because terraform is telling you that there is something wrong with the file provider and I see no mention of it in the code you added to the question.

Comment: Hi Marko, Thanks for replying
I am not aware of that file provider as i am new to terraform. Can you please tell me what is that and How to mention it to code.

Comment: Well, you have to find where in your code the file provider is used. Terraform only uses what you tell it to, so the file provider was used somewhere in your code. It can also be a misconfiguration, but unless we know where it is we cannot help, as the code in the question does not seem to be related to the error.

Comment: Hi Marko, I have edited and placed above exact code what i am using. Can you please check that and suggest me where i am facing that

Comment: The `resource "file"` is where the error is coming from. You probably wanted this: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file.

Comment: you mean i need to use `resource "local_file"` instead of this

Comment: Yes, exactly, the rest can stay the same. :) You will also have to run `terraform init` prior to running plan and apply.

Comment: Thank you Marko , Now I can able to solve this error. :)

Comment: Hi Marko, I am getting some depreciations

`Error: Unsupported argument
   on main.tf line 180, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks":
  180:     network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.azure-sg.id
 An argument named "network_security_group_id" is not expected here.`

`Error: Unsupported block type
   on main.tf line 124, in resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks":
  124:   additional_node_pools {
 Blocks of type "additional_node_pools" are not expected here.`

Comment: Sorry, I am not really proficient with Azure, it could be that a newer version of the Azure provider is required or that argument does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create AKS Cluster using Terraform:**

Kindly use the below **Terraform** code to create **AKS Cluster**.

**Terraform Code:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "venkatesh" {
  name     = "venkat-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "venkatreg" {
  name                = "Testcontainerregistery"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkatesh.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.venkatesh.location
  sku                 = "Premium"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "venkatcluster" {
  name                = "example-aks1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.venkatesh.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkatesh.name
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks1"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  principal_id                     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.venkatcluster.kubelet_identity[0].object_id
  role_definition_name             = "AcrPull"
  scope                            = azurerm_container_registry.venkatreg.id
  skip_service_principal_aad_check = true
}
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

Once ran the code resources are created successfully.

[image]

Reference:
[Create a Kubernetes cluster with Azure Kubernetes Service using Terraform.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-k8s-cluster-with-tf-and-aks)